# Api-based layout in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I apologize if this is a noob question, but i did search a lot without finding the answer i need. I'm currently startupping (my first) eCommerce hybrid app with React Native and [React Native for Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)
cause my purpose is to deploy the app for both iOS and Android, and also on mobile web browsers.

What i can't figure out till now is about the two "native" builds. How i have to manage, for example, the eCommerce navigation if it could change daily by the content managers? What if they change categories?

My first thought is that i have to render that part due an API request but, does it means i will never have that part cached? Is there an approach to cache the navigation until somehow it is invalidated due changes? I'll have a lot of "dynamic pieces" and would find a way to keep performances.

Differently the "web" version will not be builded in native so i think don't have to deal with this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main problem is the slow deployment process to the app stores, you should check [CodePush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/).

But if you have to change the home screen's top products section for example, you should write an API for that.

For caching, the API response can be stored in `AsyncStorage` or any other storage backend.

The invalidation can be solved in several ways, for example defining a validation time limit and repeat the request if it's expired or if data gathering at the backend is a compute-heavy operation, you can pass an `If-Modified-Since` header, handle it in the API, and return with `304 Not Modified` if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was wondering how much can decrease the speed of the app to have some parts of layout not built statically but loaded dynamically in the opening.

Comment: It's usually not a problem, you can fetch your initial data at app start in a few seconds.